# Register custom ConstraintValidator for existing Constraint

Tags: constraints, bean-validation, custom-validators

I use bean-validation in my project and I'd like to write a custom validator for an existing constraint annotation.

For example I have a class that represents a date/time named `CustomDateTime`. In a class that uses this class as for example a date of birth I'd like to annotate the field with `@Past`:

```
public class Person
{
    @Past
    private CustomDateTime dateOfBirth;
}
```

I then create a custom validator by implementing `ConstraintValidator<Past, CustomDateTime>`.
This however doesn't work, since the validation implementation has no knowledge of the custom validator. It then throws: `javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: com.example.CustomDateTime`.

I know that you usually create a separate annotation like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomDateTimePastValidator.class})
public @interface Past
{
    ....
}
```

But that seems like double code to me ;-)

How can I register the custom validator to be used with `@Past`?

Answer (score 5):

You can define an [XML-based constraint mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#d0e2308) which adds your constraint validator for the existing `@Past` constraint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">

    <constraint-definition annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Past">
        <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
            <value>com.acme.CustomDateTimePastValidator</value>
        </validated-by>
    </constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

Then either reference this mapping in your [validation.xml](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#d0e2218):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">

    <constraint-mapping>/path/to/constraint-mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

Or you add it during bootstrapping your validator:

```
InputStream mappingStream = ...;

Validator validator = Validation
    .byDefaultProvider()
    .configure()
    .addMapping( mappingStream )
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```